# Reasons to use SupervisorJob over Job in a custom CoroutineScope

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I'm trying to understand Kotlin coroutines better, specifically scopes. I created a new project with the following code:

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    companion object {

        const val TAG = "coroutines"

        val scope = CoroutineScope(Job() + CoroutineExceptionHandler { _, e -> Log.e(TAG, "", e) })
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        scope.launch {
            Log.v(TAG, "launch 1")
            delay(3000)
            Log.d(TAG, "completed launch 1")
        }

        scope.launch {
            Log.v(TAG, "launch 2")
            throw Exception()
        }
    }
}
```

As expected, when an exception occurs in launch 2, launch 1 never completes as all the children of `scope` are cancelled. I then replaced `Job()` with `SupervisorJob()` and also as expected launch 1 now completes.

My question is: Given that without the `CoroutineExceptionHandler` the app simply crashes, is there any reason to use `SupervisorJob()` over `Job()` if an exception handler is not set? Are there other conditions under which a child coroutine can fail without throwing an exception?

Comment: Normally we don't use such custom scopes on Android at all. Android already provides you with the two relevant scopes -- one for the lifecycle of a view, another for the lifecycle of the app.

Comment: As for the exceptions, you should handle them within the coroutines. An unhandled exception _should_ crash the app, just like in any other Android code.

Comment: If you're creating a CoroutineScope without managing its lifecycle (canceling it when it's no longer useful), then it serves no purpose and you might as well be using GlobalScope.  So the above example is kind of nonsensical anyway because you're storing it in an `object` (making it static). In an Activity, it's usually appropriate to use the provided `lifecycleScope`. You might want to create a separate scope to manage a group of coroutines that belong together and should be cancelled all at once under some situation other than the activity being destroyed.

Comment: In that case, whether to use Job vs. SupervisorJob depends on whether it makes sense for them to all be cancelled if any one of them fails. It's situation dependent.

Comment: @Tenfour04 yes, that makes sense. I just wanted to know if I was missing something. Marko Topolnik already pointed out the pre-made scopes are typically applied to this situation.

Comment: I'd argue that, when you have a collection of coroutines belonging to a unit of work, you'll have one top-level coroutine, a `coroutineScope` block inside it, and inside that block you launch as many child coroutines as you need. Still no need for a custom top-level scope object.